# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException while reading csv from S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

We are trying to read some partners data from their S3 using spark. We have the following code set up for that puprose:

```
S3_BUCKET = 'BUCKET_NAME'
ROLE_SESSION_NAME = 'SESSION_NAME'
BASE_ROLE_ARN = 'BASE_ROLE_ARN/'
ROLE_ARN = BASE_ROLE_ARN + ROLE_NAME
DURATION_SECONDS = 3600
client = boto3.client('sts')
role = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=ROLE_ARN,
    RoleSessionName=ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    DurationSeconds=DURATION_SECONDS,
    ExternalId=EXTERNAL_ID
)
s3_session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=role['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=role['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=role['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
s3_credentials = s3_session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
s3_key = s3_credentials.access_key
s3_secret = s3_credentials.secret_key
s3_session_token = s3_credentials.token
```

We then use the following code to read the data:

```
input_path = 's3a://some_input_path/'
input_data = spark_sql_context.read.csv(input_path, header = True)
```

Also, we make sure that everything is set correctly as for spark config:

```
    spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.access.key", s3_key
    )
    spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.secret.key", s3_secret
    )
    spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider"
    )
    spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.session.token", s3_session_token
    )
```

But when trying to read the data, we see the following exception:

```
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://the_input_path: getFileStatus on s3a://the_input_path: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: F08F9B987FF8DED9; S3 Extended Request ID: TRjfFjALAk7phRDxKdUlucY4yocQY2mNO4r7N6Qf9fSDzSa+TpZfimwbAzXdU+s11BBLBblfgik=), S3 Extended Request ID: TRjfFjALAk7phRDxKdUlucY4yocQY2mNO4r7N6Qf9fSDzSa+TpZfimwbAzXdU+s11BBLBblfgik=:403 Forbidden
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1683)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:2976)
```

This gets more weird as the following code snippet works just fine:

```
import os
import boto3
import sys
ROLE_NAME             = 'ROLE_NAME'
EXTERNAL_ID           = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
S3_BUCKET             = 'BUCKET_NAME'
# ------------------------------------------------ DO NOT ALTER BELOW ------------------------------------------------ #
ROLE_SESSION_NAME     = 'SESSION_NAME'
BASE_ROLE_ARN         = 'BASE_ROLE_ARN'
ROLE_ARN              = BASE_ROLE_ARN + ROLE_NAME
DURATION_SECONDS      = 3600
client = boto3.client('sts')
role = client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=ROLE_ARN,
    RoleSessionName=ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    DurationSeconds=DURATION_SECONDS,
    ExternalId=EXTERNAL_ID
)
session = boto3.session.Session(
                aws_access_key_id=role['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                aws_secret_access_key=role['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                aws_session_token=role['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
S3 = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = S3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='SOME_PREFIX'):
    print (object_summary.key)
```

Any idea why we might be seeing that exception while trying to read files from the S3 path using spark? Are we missing something?

Comment: did you check either  you have the read right on the bucket from where you read your CSVs ?

Comment: @NassereddineBelghith I do have the read access to that bucket. As mentioned, the boto3 connection works just one and I am able to read stuff from that specific path.

Comment: ahh I see try to follow this link it may help https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-403-access-denied/